# Definite Integration With Trig Functions and Euler's Number

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, approximation

I'm trying to calculate a welfare function as a definite integral, and the part I'm having trouble with is the consumer curve function. In econ, this is done as

$\text{CS}=\int_{0}^{Q^{\ast}} \left[f \left(Q\right)- P^{\ast} \right] dQ$ or

$\text{CS}=\int_{0}^{6.0509} \left[22e^{-\arctan{\left(Q\right)}}- 5.3872 \right] dQ$, where  $P^\ast=5.3872$ is the price equilibrium and $6.0509$ is the approximate equilibrium for the quantity demanded.

I've never calculated an integral involving Euler's number or, for that matter, one that used a negative inverse tangent function. Any ideas as to how I might get started on this or solve it? I've never seen a problem like this before.

Comment: Everything inside the square brackets is just a number. With a scientific calculator, evaluate the exponent first, then raise  e  to that power. A bit more arithmetic and you have the number to be integrated. Since it is a constant, you may bring it outside the integral.

Comment: My apologies, I should've retained the Q in the integral. I'm not integrating a constant, instead I'm integrating the area under the curve. So I still plug in 6.0509 and then evaluate, or is additional work needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing
$$I=\int e^{-\tan ^{-1}(x)}\,dx$$ is very difficult (the result involves gaussian hypergeometric functions).

It would better to generate a table for
$$J(t)=\int_0^t e^{-\tan ^{-1}(x)}\,dx$$ and interpolate between values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
t & J(t) \\
 0 & 0.00000 \\
 1 & 0.66225 \\
 2 & 1.04267 \\
 3 & 1.34828 \\
 4 & 1.62339 \\
 5 & 1.88232 \\
 6 & 2.13129 \\
 7 & 2.37353 \\
 8 & 2.61092 \\
 9 & 2.84466 \\
 10 & 3.07555
\end{array}
\right)$$

Interpolating in this table, we have
$$\int_0^{6.0509} e^{-\tan ^{-1}(x)}\,dx=2.14377$$ So
$$\text{CS}=22\times 2.14377-5.3872\times 6.0509=14.5655$$ while numerical integration would give $14.5654$